# Need to Adjust Screen Edge of an HDMI-connected TV

Tags: hdmi, intel-graphics

I have a Linux Mint Debian Edition device that I'm connecting to my Sony Bravia TV via HDMI. The resolution of both screens are 1920x1080.

But when I connect them via HDMI cable, the PC screen is edged correctly with no off-screen edges, but the TV has off-screen edges on its four directions (top, bottom, left, right). How to do I adjust the screen alignment so it fits correctly?

Can't do that from TV since the adjustment options are greyed out: "these settings don't support connected signal" or something to that effect.

I had the same problem before with Windows 8, but I used Intel HD Graphics 4000 settings to adjust the edge of the connected display, how do I do that on Linux since Intel doesn't have similar software for it.